# program that does something the amount of times a user tells it to not working

Tags: python

I am working in python 3. I am trying to make a program that does something the amount of times a user tells it to. for some reason it is not working. here is my code:

```
times = input("amount of times: ")
number = 0
while number < int(times):
     print ("hello")
     number + 1
```

What is my problem

Comment: `number+1` should be `number += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

you are not incrementing `number` which leads to an infinite loop. 
it should be `number+=1`

Answer (score 0):

```
while number < int(times):
 print ("hello")
 number =number+ 1
```

Try it out

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a for loop, depending on the program.
Something like this should work for you

```
times = input("amount of times: ")
for number in range(int(times)):
    print("hello")
```